# All available hooks in protractor

Tags: protractor

Is there any link which provides information on all available hooks in protractor. 
For Instance, in webdriverIO we have the below :

```
    onPrepare: function (config, capabilities) {},

    beforeSession: function (config, capabilities, specs) {},

    before: function (capabilities, specs) {},

    beforeSuite: function (suite) {},

    beforeHook: function () {},

    afterHook: function () {},

    beforeTest: function (test) {},

    beforeCommand: function (commandName, args) {},

    afterCommand: function (commandName, args, result, error) {},

    afterTest: function (test) {},

    afterSuite: function (suite) {},

    after: function (result, capabilities, specs) {},

    afterSession: function (config, capabilities, specs) {},

    onComplete: function (exitCode, config, capabilities, results) {},

    onReload: function(oldSessionId, newSessionId) {},
```

I am looking for similar hooks in protractor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't ensure these are 100% comprehensive but this is something I generated a while ago. Protractor and Jasmine hooks in the order they run.

```
--- beforeLaunch           
    --- onPrepare          
      --- jasmineStarted   (set in jasmine reporter)
        --- beforeAll
         --- suiteStarted  (set in jasmine reporter)
          --- specStarted  (set in jasmine reporter)
           --- beforeEach  
           +++ afterEach   
          +++ specDone     (set in jasmine reporter)
         +++ suiteDone     (set in jasmine reporter)
        +++ afterAll
      +++ jasmineDone      (set in jasmine reporter)
    +++ onComplete         
+++ afterLaunch
```

If there are further hooks I have missed I would also appreciate someone pointing them out to here.

You can read more about Protractor hooks [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts) and more about the Jasmine hooks [here](https://jasmine.github.io/api/3.3/Reporter.html)

**Additional code based on comment**

```
onComplete: function (passed) {
    if (!passed) {
        request({
            uri: https: '//${browserstack.user}:${browserstack.key}@api.browserstack.com/automate/sessions/${ browser.sessionId }.json', method: 'PUT', form: { status: 'error' },
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I need to add a api request in my protractor config file to  update the test results to pass/fail after each test in Browserstack. I am confused if I have to user onComplete or afterLaunch ? I am pretty much sure I cannot use the afterAll or afterLaunch in the config. But I could not get it to work when I use onComplete

Comment: Adding the code.
 onComplete:function(failures) {
   if (failures) {
     request({
        uri:`https://${browserstack.user}:${browserstack.key}@api.browserstack.com/automate/sessions/${
             browser.sessionId
           }.json`,
        method:'PUT',
        form: {
          status:'error'
        },
      });
    }
  },

Comment: Are you using Protractor with Jasmine?

Comment: Yes. Protractor with Jasmine

Comment: I'll admit I have not used a parameter for onComplete as you are attempt but from looking [at this jasmine doc](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/ed955e56a839d7f69da43acb6755763220d3681d/lib/frameworks/jasmine.js#L111) it appears that the parameter it accepts is actually for 'passed' and not 'failures'. I have edited my answer with some code, can you check it out and let me know.

Comment: Makes sense to me. I will try doing this way. thanks for your help

Comment: Cool, let me know if it works. If it does not you should be able to achieve similar functionality by creating a new Jasmine reporters in one of your earlier hooks

Answer (score 0):

Protractor is just a wrapper for selenium-webdriver so they don't have any hooks. I suspect you are looking using a framework to drive your tests like jamsmine or cucumber so you will need to use their hooks. Think of it like Protractor being the car and jasmine being the driver telling the car what to do and when to do it.

There is 1 hook(not really a hook but similar) that you can use and that is the onPrepare in the protractor config file.